# Jieli BR21 Bluetooth dongle shown as storage device

Tags: bluetooth

Result of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID e5b7:0811 ZhuHai JieLi Technology JieLi BR21
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04ca:00ac Lite-On Technology Corp. Dell Wireless Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

The third line is my Bluetooth device. But the Bluetooth still doesn't work. May be a driver issue. I have tried almost all the answers available through googling. Please help me.

Comment: What does not working mean? Is there an error? What are the exact steps you have followed?

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this works with Ubuntu 22.04.  Using at terminal **lsusb** lists  as:  "ID 4c4a:4155 Jieli Technology USB Composite Device".  The packaging lists as "PC-T7 JieLi BR17 PC Music Transmitter BT up to Ver 5.0". It takes a while to be recognized so be patient.  Once recognized the blue LED on the dongle will flash to indicate pairing mode.  Once dongle LED flashes Turn on your Bluetooth audio device, in my case bluetooth headphones.  I then put the headphones in pairing mode and headphones was automatically picked up and paired by Lieli USB.  Until the headphones paired I had no visual indication in Ubuntu (using KDE) that BR17 was detected.  Once connected it was listed in KDE sound settings.  Only been using for one day but so far happy.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you connected – IS NOT a Bluetooth dongle. It's USB sound card. Bluetooth inside is only for receiving audio stream from something like PC or smartphone and playing.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know, those things are soundcards with bluetooth recieving capebility, not bluetooth sticks. They can't connect to any non-audio devices, and will only transmit/recieve audio to the USB-audio driver.

Comment: Google them it says they can.

Comment: @David edited my message. my main point still stands